# Вопрос по сериализации в Java

Tags: java, десериализация

В классе `ObjectInput` есть метод `available()`, который, как написано в java docs, возвращает количество байт, доступных для чтения без блокировки. В классе `FileInputStream` этот метод возвращает корректное количество байт, а тут всегда 0, хотя для чтения есть байты. В связи с этим вопросы:

1. Что значит без блокировки, и почему метод возвращает 0, хотя в файле есть непрочитанные сериализованные объекты?
2. Как делать проверку, есть ли в файле данные(объекты) для считывания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`без блокировки` значит, что при запросе такого количества байт поток, исполняющий запрос не будет приостановлен до получения новой порции данных. Т.е. это значит, что в стриме гарантировано есть `available` байт.

Метод `available()` возвращает *оценочное* количество байт для чтения без блокировки. Например, для `InputStream` он всегда возвращает 0. Видимо, стрим, на котором ты реализуешь десереализацию, по каким-то внутренним причинам не может вернуть точное количество доступных байт, поэтому он возвращает 0 (что тоже валидное значение, говорящее о том, что нет гарантии, что твой вызов закончится без блокировки).

Из файла читаем все доступные объекты, ловя `EOFException`:

```
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis))
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            SerializableClass sc = (SerializableClass) ois.readObject();
            /// ... do some additional work
        }
        catch (EOFException ignore)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Догадывался,  что нужно делать через исключения.  Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Джавадок неверен.

`available` возвращает число байт записанных в поток методом `write(byte[])`.

Вот небольшой пример для иллюстрации.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

            stream.writeObject(A.builder().i(1).j(2).build());
            stream.write(new byte[7]);
            stream.close();

            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

            System.out.println("available = " + inputStream.available());
            System.out.println("o = " + inputStream.readObject());

            System.out.println("available = " + inputStream.available());
            System.out.println("byte = " + inputStream.read());
            System.out.println("available = " + inputStream.available());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Data
    @Builder
    static class A implements Serializable {
        int i;
        int j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Действительно,  спасибо

Comment: Спасибо в карму не приплюсуешь :)